# How to get to the next level of Assocation in an EF4 EntityDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, entitydatasource

I've used EF4 EntityDataSources to do DataBinding with success, but here's a case where I'm stumped:

Table "CurrentComplaintsByUsers" has a foreign key over to a "Complaints" table. So in EF, I can access a CurrentComplaintByUser record, and navigate to its parent complaint like so:

```
var ccU = dataContext.CurrentComplaintsByUsers.First();
var parentComplaint = ccU.Complaint;
```

When I whip up an EntityDataSource based on CurrentComplaintsByUsers to bind a gridview, I want to get over from the "Complaint" object to an Assocation of Complaint called "Status". Here's a StatusID in my Complaint table, and so in code I can hit a complaint's status like so, including the Status properties:

```
string statusLabel = parentComplaint.Status.LabelText;
```

***FAILURE:*** when I try to bake this all into an EntityDataSource, I can't get from my starting item "CurrentComplaintsByUsers" over to "Status". Here's my EDS:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsCurrentCases" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="name=EOCaseDataModel" DefaultContainerName="EOCaseDataModel" 
     EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CurrentComplaintsByUsers" 
     Include="Complaint, Status">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

My error is this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
"A specified Include path is not valid. 
The EntityType 'EOCaseApp.CurrentComplaintsByUser' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Status'."
```

I'm trying to get to the point where this works in my Gridview:

```
<%# ((CurrentComplaintsByUser)Container.DataItem).Complaint.Status.LabelText %>
```

So, **using declaritive markup only**, how do I get to a related objects associations from the EDS? *(I can do it in code, just trying to use the EDS exclusively when I can)*

Other notes: if I remove "Status" from the "Include" in the EDS, then I get a NULL ERROR when it hits ..Complaint.Status.LabelText in my Gridview, pretty much what you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `Include="Complaint, Status"` to `Include="Complaint, Complaint.Status"` in your EntityDataSource

Comment: AHHHH. Thank you, you magnificent bastard. Totally works. On a side note, i HAATEE EF4's requirement to spell out your relationships as opposed to Linq-2-Sql's pattern of apply them as needed.